# Cannot update a component while rendering a different component (React Native)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am aware this question has been asked a few times before but I still cant find a decent solution for the problem I am facing.
I have a main screen (called A) and it's a bit like this:

```
const [steps, setSteps] = useState();
If (steps === 1){
   nextStep = <ComponentA1 setSteps={setSteps} />
  }
If (steps === 2){
   nextStep = <ComponentA2 setSteps={setSteps} />
  }
If (steps === 3){
   navigation.navigate(NewScreen, ....)
  }

return <View>{nextStep}</View>
```

the 'subcomponents' look a bit like this:

```
 ...
function handler() {
    setSteps(2) //or 3 or 4 ...
   }
return(
   <View>Display Something</View>
   <Button onPress={handler}>
    )
```

Everything works fine, a new component is being show when clicked on the button. But as soon as steps become 3, I get the error message that I cannot update a component (`ForwardRef(BaseNavigationContainer)`) while rendering a different component (A).
This message appears but the newScreen renders like it should.
I can ignore this error message but it keeps me annoyed and I want to find a solution for it.

I tried already:

- using useEffect
- in the return part of A:

  {(steps === 2)? navigation to ... : {nextStep}} (or something like this)
- replace instead of navigate
- putting the navigation in componentC so I dont update the steps

  function handler() {
  navigation.navigate(newScreen, ...)

but it keeps on giving me the same error message.
What am I doing wrong? What do I need to change so it works without giving this error message?

Thx,
Peter

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see above, what you are doing is returning the method to navigate to another screen, instead of returning a component when `steps === 3`.
What you can do is use a useEffect to handle the steps when the step changes to 3, because you always need to return a component or null, something like this:

```js
const [steps, setSteps] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {
  if (steps === 3) {
    navigation.navigate(NewScreen, ....)
  }
}, [steps])

if(steps === 1) {
  return <ComponentA1 setSteps={setSteps}/>
}
if(steps === 2) {
  return <ComponentA2 setSteps={setSteps}/>
}
return <DefaultViewOrComponent { ...props}/>
```

I hope this helps